# How i will log into slack from Asp.Net MVC web application by passing email and password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, slack, slack-api

I need to auto login to Slack workspace by passing email and password as parameters from my asp.net MVC application.

There will be a link called "Slack Login" in my web application and I need to auto login to slack Workspace without redirecting to username/password page.

Need to pass both parameters through code and redirect to slack workspace screen automatically.  How I will achieve this scenario ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The [Slack Sign-in process](https://api.slack.com/docs/sign-in-with-slack) always requires the user to manually enter his username and password to sign-in. I would assume that its designed that way for security reasons.